# Is JavaFX GUI heavy for the performance?

Tags: java, performance, swing, javafx

I am learning JavaFX, and it seems very cool, but pretty nasty too. As far as I got it, the GUI is written in XML, and exported in the exact same form (not being converted or anything), and the XML is being read with `FXMLLoader`, every time the window opens up. Also, JavaFX has much more features than swing (rotating, 3D, etc). So my question is:

**Is JavaFX significantly heavier for the performance, comparing to Java Swing?** If it is not, then how heavy is it?

Comment: You can write JavaFX programs without using XML.  Besides that, you question is very open-ended - heavy for performance for what?  If you want to compare performance for a given task, you would need to create two programs in the different UI toolkits that you want to compare performance on and then run benchmarks on both - I suggest you give that a try.  Or create a tech prototype for your target app and validate that performance in your candidate toolkit is acceptable for your app.

Comment: The minimal requirements are higher and the memory footprint too. Moreover, the performance is less consistent across platforms than with Swing because it is more hardware accelerated with several distinct backends like the old versions of Java 3D (<= 1.5.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the early days of JavaFX, I tried it out to show a large graph (thousands or tens of thousands of nodes and edges), and found that it was slow compared to displaying the same graph structure in Swing.  However, most user interfaces are much simpler than what I was displaying, so any speed difference is irrelevant.  Since those early days Oracle has put a lot of work into making JavaFX as fast as Swing.  Today's performance in JavaFX is much closer to the performance of swing.

Here is a writeup of someone experience in switching from Swing to JavaFX:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/casa-1919152.html

The author says:
*Performance—Our overall impression is that JavaFX provides the same high level of performance as Swing when it comes to assembling and rendering screens with many components. And JavaFX provides much better performance in the area of transitions and animations (Swing provides very limited functionality in this area). Overall, performance is not an issue.*